# pdf,doc,xls file upload in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-mvc

How to upload all document files Like PDF, DOCX,XLS to mysql Database using java and JPA and Spring
Thanks in advance

Comment: how to google `uploading files using java`

Answer (score 1):

I did come across a similar situation but with Minor Modifications of your requirement.., like

- DB  - Oracle 11g     (Instead of mySql)
- IDE - jDeveloper 11  (To take care of Java, Swings - MVC)

If you'r cool with this modification plz have a look how I developed this,

Flow: UI(Pass the file)--->(Processing by IDE)--->DB(Data Saved)

Create a DB Schema:(2 Coloumns)

- Info  - Varchar 2 (Data Type)
- Media - Blob

Now that done with DB, Come to IDE & create a .jspx Page (Without Backing Bean!), Drag & Drop InputFile Component from Component Palette. Create a Managed bean and write the following code to recieve the file as Parameter from UI & process further.

Code:-

```
public class Upload()
{     
   private UploadedFile _file;

   public void setFile(UploadedFile _file) {
       this._file = _file;
   }

   public UploadedFile getFile() {
       return _file;
   }

   public String UploadMedia(){

       UploadedFile myFile = (UploadedFile)this.getFile();

       System.out.println("****************************************************");

       BindingContext bc = BindingContext.getCurrent();
       BindingContainer bindings = bc.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
       DCBindingContainer dbc = (DCBindingContainer)bindings;
       DCIteratorBinding iter = dbc.findIteratorBinding("MediadbVO1Iterator");

       Row row = iter.getCurrentRow();
       row.setAttribute("Media", createBlobDomain(myFile));
       return null;
   }

   private BlobDomain createBlobDomain(UploadedFile file) {
       InputStream in = null;
       BlobDomain blobDomain = null;
       OutputStream out = null;

       try {
           in = file.getInputStream();

           blobDomain = new BlobDomain();
           out = blobDomain.getBinaryOutputStream();
           byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
           int bytesRead = 0;

           while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
               out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           }

           in.close();

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.fillInStackTrace();
       }

       return blobDomain;

   }
}
```

Set the "Value" field of InputFile Component as "`#{backing_Upload.file}`"
where backing_Upload is my bean name with file as Paramater.

Now Drag & Drop a Command Button & set its Action Field as "`#{backing_Upload.UploadMedia}`"
where backing_Upload is my bean name and UploadMedia is my method.

Hope you achieve what you desired on selecting file & clicking Button the file gets stored to DB.

Comment: Thanks for your code and let me try to implement,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store files in a DATABASE, but can store their location in the table.

Comment: well you can store Files as a BLOB in the database. but i agree that you should store the path to the file in the database and the file itself on the fs.

Comment: @Nicolas : thanks for replay but i know that BLOB type but u have any code or example then please tell me and data of file will be in which format that means byte, string or any thing else, Thanks in advance